# Read range of data line by line which is increasing dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I need to read or clear all the line in specific range which will be increasing dynamically.
Problem is "Selected File List" table range is not specified. New file chosen with browse will be added to "Selected File List" dynamically. Number of file can't be predicted.

[image]

What I've tried so far is, keep track of the browse button click and add the file path to arraylist.
After that, (Row number 9 which is start line + arraylist size) to get the number of line of end of the table.
But due to some requirement, I want to read the file from excel file. Something like -Read until found blank line or border bottom or something.

I'm new to VBA and I'm not so sure what I'm doing with vba codes so please be kind :D

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided there is no blank cell within the list of files, you could give the heading cell ("Selected File List") a name, e.g. "SelFiles" and do something like this ...

```
Sub Test()
    ' call the function
    Debug.Print getSize(Range("SelFiles"), True)

End Sub

Function getSize(MyRange As Range, Optional HasHeader As Boolean = False)
Dim Idx As Integer

    Idx = 2
    Do While MyRange(Idx, 1) <> ""
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
    If HasHeader Then
        getSize = Idx - 2
    Else
        getSize = Idx - 1
    End If
End Function
```

The function uses a bit of abstraction, you can use it for ranges including / excluding ranges. You may have other areas in your application where you need to count rows, so the use of a function is preferred to just adding the loop into the code of your main Sub().

Comment: It works! Thank you @MikeD . Sorry for late accept. I've been trying to understand the code. :)

Comment: @MinNaingOo ... yeep I thought it was maybe usefull to give you some pointers to write reuseable code

Comment: Can you help me explain one thing? Why `Range("FilesToMerge").Range(2, 1).Select` doesn't work? It says "Application-defined or object-defined error". What I want to do is to select the row under Name Range given cell. In above fig, the cell "File4.csv" locate. :)

Comment: because `.Range(2,1)` is wrong syntax ... the Range property needs either 1 or 2 Cell objects (whereby Cell is another Range object of exactly 1 cell) ... you can do `Range("FilesToMerge").Cells(2, 1).Select`